# AWS AppSync - Javascript Resolver - DynamoDB Batch Query

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I want to write a `batch query` that will return all of the `items` from the dynamo db who's `ReviewStatus` is equal to one of the statuses in the `status` array

---

i know that if the status was a string i could write

```js
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils';

export function request(ctx) {
  const { limit = 20, nextToken, status } = ctx.arguments;
  const index = 'ReviewStatus-index';
  const query = JSON.parse( 
    util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression({ 
        ReviewStatus: { 
             eq: status 
        } 
    })
  );
  
  return { operation: 'Query', index, query, limit, nextToken };
}

export function response(ctx) {
  const { items, nextToken } = ctx.result;
  return { items, nextToken };
}
```

but what about if status was an array ?

I thought I tried many different queries but none worked

Ideally something like the code below would be nice if it worked

```js
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils';

export function request(ctx) {
  const { limit = 20, nextToken, status } = ctx.arguments;
  const index = 'ReviewStatus-index';
  const query = JSON.parse( 
    util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression({
        "or": status.map( s => ({ ReviewStatus: { eq: s } }))
    })
  );
  
  return { operation: 'Query', index, query, limit, nextToken };
}

export function response(ctx) {
  const { items, nextToken } = ctx.result;
  return { items, nextToken };
}
```

i would even appreciate any resources that could help me figure this out
i looked in the documentation but they only have information about batch queries in VTL templates not in Javascript templates